# Action editor / dope sheet showing extra frame without any keyframes

Tags: dopesheet

As shown in the attached image, my 60 frame animation has a empty frame 61, as shown by the darker shade on the header and all other lines.

How do I find what it causing this so I can remove it? When I export via fbx 61 frames are shown for the action.

I've tried ensuring nothing is hidden, and bones are displayed. I also have the 'ghost' option on to show hidden.

[image: dark area shows frame 61 exists]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause, I had keyframed scale on one bone, should all be loc/rot only. Removing the scale from the bone fixed the issue.